# Pre-populate product data in mongoDB collection

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I am developing a meteor and react application. I want to pre-populate data into my Product collection so that it will display products on the client server side when they run the app. It would contain fields such as :

```
ProductName: String,
ProductPrice: Number,
ProductCategory: String,
ProductDescription: String,
ProductImage: Image,
ProductTrackingLink: string,
ProductBrand: string,
```

Roughly about 10 products. How should I go about this?

I tried adding it into my mongo collection. However, I was not sure if this was the correct way to do it.

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'

export const ProductsCollection = new Mongo.Collection('products')
```

Update: This is what I have done so far in my collection class:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { ProductsCollection } from './ProductsCollection'

Meteor.startup(() => {
    if (ProductsCollection.find().count() === 0) {
        ProductsCollection.insert({
            ProductID: 1,
            ProductName: "Product1",
            ProductDescription: "Product1 Description",
            ProductPrice: 100,
            ProductImage: "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url",
            ProductCategory: "Controller",
            ProductTrackinglink: "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url",
            ProductBrand: "PlayStation",
            createdAt: new Date(),
        });
```

Comment: my answer should solve your issue, if so, please accept, otherwise please comment

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you could do.

### A - Hard-Coded JSON file

Put all your data in a JSON file `products.json` and place this close to the file you run the startup code:

```json
[
  {
    "ProductID": "1",
    "ProductName": "Product1",
    "ProductDescription": "Product1 Description",
    "ProductPrice": 100,
    "ProductImage": "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url",
    "ProductCategory": "Controller",
    "ProductTrackinglink": "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url",
    "ProductBrand": "PlayStation",
  }
]
```

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { ProductsCollection } from './ProductsCollection'
import productsList from './products.json'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  if (ProductsCollection.find().count() === 0) {
    productList.forEach(doc => {
      ProductsCollection.insert({
        ...doc,
        createdAt: new Date(),
      })
    })
  }
})
```

- advantage: check in to the repo (unless it contains sensitive data that is not meant to be seen on the client)
- disadvantage: hard to refactor

### B - Use Meteor.settings

The other approach is to put this into the `settings.json` file as own namespace:

```json
{
  ... your other settings
  "fixtures": {
    "products": [
      ...see products.json list above
    ]
  }
}
```

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { ProductsCollection } from './ProductsCollection'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  if (ProductsCollection.find().count() === 0) {
    Meteor.settings.fixtures.products.forEach(doc => {
      ProductsCollection.insert({
        ...doc,
        createdAt: new Date(),
      })
    })
  }
})
```

- advantage: this is more flexible if you have different deployments where each requires a different set of pre-populated products
- disadvantage: bloats the settings file